# AWK - Unable to substitute the value

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have to replace the days of a month from 1 to 9 as 01 to 09. I did that based on the below code

```
echo "1"|awk '{gsub('1',"01")}1'
echo "2"|awk '{gsub('2',"02")}1'
```

But now all the other days like 10,11 are getting replaced as 010 , 011 
Please guide me as how to write it so that only the single digit days gets prefixed with 0. Thanks

Comment: **think** about what your attempted use of `'`s inside a `'`-delimited script is really doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `gawk` ?

```
echo "1 2 11 21" | gawk '{gsub(/\y[0-9]\y/,"0&")}1'
01 02 11 21
```

Used the word boundary regular expression from gawk. More [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html)

---

Example from the comments:

```
$ cat file1
Date: Sep 5 2017
Date: Sep 15 2017
Some other line

$ cat file1 | gawk '/^Date:/ { gsub(/\y[0-9]\y/,"0&",$3); sub(/Sep/,"09",$2); print "EndDate "$4$2$3 }'
EndDate 20170905
EndDate 20170915
```

Comment: Make it `gsub(/\y[0-9]\y/,"0&")` to possibly be useful (though @Kents `printf` solution is better unless the digits are embedded in other text).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @hakan baba. Unfortunately it is still not giving the required answer. My input is     Date:   Sep 5 2017  and this is my code     if (substr($0,5,5) == "Date:") {gawk gsub(/\y[0-9]\y/,"0&",$3); sub(/Sep/, "09",$2) ; print "EndDate "$4$2$3 > "output.txt"; next }                  For current date, I am getting the correct output as 20170905 , but if I change my input as    Date:   Sep 15 2017     then my output is  2017090105

Comment: @madsthiru I have updated my answer with your example. It works as expected for me.

Comment: @Hakan Baba Thank you so much. It is working perfectly for me

Answer (score 3):

instead of `gsub()`, `printf` is the function you are looking for, see the example:

```
kent$ seq 12|awk '{printf "%02d\n", $0}'
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
```

Comment: Or even skip `awk` in favor of `xargs printf`. Depends on what OP really wants to do.

Comment: @Kevin you are right. but I *guess*, OP has a dateformat string, and just want to pad the month. He made the example simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In bash recent versions, you can use

```
echo {01..12}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
```

Another option is to use format specifier in `seq`.

```
seq -f "%02g" 12
```

**OUTPUT**

```
01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
02                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
03                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
04                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
05                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
06                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
07                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
08                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
09                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
12
```